# Rows of text with same width but different font sizes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

Are there any simple way to align rows of text with different font sizes so that the text rows have the same width.

I would like to do this in Photoshop, Illustrator and Premiere Pro.

Comment: Besides the "justify text" mentioned in the answers are you not defining the text block by dragging out the area within which to place the text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how it works for CS6 at least.

You're looking for the *Justify tool*.

You make sure all the text elements have the same width. Then you select the text in the element, open up Window -> Paragraph, and select the 'Justify all' option (out most to the right in the Paragraph dialogue). This will distribute the space width for the text so that every row is the entire width of the text container. Do this for all text elements.

Answer (score 0):

just a little addition if you used the text tool by selecting it and click so you start typing it won't happen with justify.
First you should determine each text block to be same size (use the text tool as marquee tool(M)) in order to build text blocks with same sizes.